# angularjs - how to convert large string object into chunk of key/value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, object

I took data from a text file i.e sample_resume.txt

Name: John Doe 
Phone: (555) 555-5555 
Email: johndoe@example.com

OBJECTIVE 
Excel in a web developer career.

KEY SKILLS
Development: HTML5, JavaScript, Bootstrap, AngularJS, ReactJS, CSS3, Media Queries, Development
Project Management: JIRA, Bitbucket, Confluence, Git, GitHub

EMPLOYMENT HISTORY
Title: Junior Web Developer
Company: Apple Inc. 
Dates: June 2015 to September 2016
* Developed responsive corporate websites
* Did some cool stuff
* Led team in closing out JIRA bugs

and imported it into my angular project using a controller
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http) {

```
$http.get('../../documents/sample_resume.txt')
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.info = data;


    }, function (error) {

        alert('error');
    });
```

});

I expected the output in Json format to be divided in to key value pairs of the data but the output is

{"data":"Name: John Doe \r\nPhone: (555) 555-5555 \r\nEmail: johndoe@example.com\r\n\r\nOBJECTIVE \r\nExcel in a web developer career.\r\n\r\nKEY SKILLS\r\nDevelopment: HTML5, JavaScript, Bootstrap, AngularJS, ReactJS, CSS3, Media Queries, Development\r\nProject Management: JIRA, Bitbucket, Confluence, Git, GitHub\r\n\r\nEMPLOYMENT HISTORY\r\nTitle: Junior Web Developer\r\nCompany: Apple Inc. \r\nDates: June 2015 to September 2016\r\n* Developed responsive corporate websites\r\n* Did some cool stuff\r\n* Led team in closing out JIRA bugs\r\n\r\nTitle: Web Development Intern \r\nCompany: Google Inc.\r\nDates: January 2015 to May 2015\r\n* Went on coffee runs for the team\r\n* Team record for longest keg stand\r\n* Once ate 82 cupcakes during a team building event\r\n\r\nEDUCATION\r\nDegree: BBA \r\nSchool: Michigan State University\r\nGPA: 2.2\r\nMajor: Computer Science\r\nMinor: Drinking","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"../../documents/sample_resume.txt","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}

i need the data, split into key value pairs like:
{"Name": "John Doe",
Phone: (555) 555-5555}

Comment: What does *"display in chunks"* mean? Where is the code that generates the output? Problem really isn't clear without more detail. Also you are probably aren't logging the `data` property of the response object

Comment: Is this json data something you control? or will you need to parse the data in the data property into key value pairs?

Comment: the data is normal text. example:     Name: John Doe 
Phone: (555) 555-5555 
Email: johndoe@example.com

OBJECTIVE 
Excel in a web developer career.

KEY SKILLS
Development: HTML5, JavaScript, Bootstrap, AngularJS, ReactJS, CSS3, Media Queries, Development
Project Management: JIRA, Bitbucket, Confluence, Git, GitHub

EMPLOYMENT HISTORY
Title: Junior Web Developer
Company: Apple Inc. 
Dates: June 2015 to September 2016
* Developed responsive corporate websites
* Did some cool stuff
* Led team in closing out JIRA bugs

Title: Web Development Intern

Comment: used controller to get the data form the file: app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.json = 'Data not yet loaded.';
    $http.get('../../documents/sample_resume.txt')
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.info = data;
            

        }, function (error) {

            alert('error');
        });
});

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of this. Suggest reading [ask] then update question content with consice details

Comment: Please format your JSON code to help people read it and also benefit from your question and its answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if parsing the text into an array of key value pairs, splitted by the ":" in the text, this code will do what you want. However, if you actually control this text file output, I would consider making it a json file with exact structure you need.

I am asuming AngularJS here, hence putting the "kvp" array on the scope.

```
var lines = response.data.split('\r\n'); //split by the newlines
$scope.kvp = [];
lines.forEach(function(line, index) {
  var pair = line.split(':'); //split by colon
  if (pair.length === 2) { //do we have a pair?
    $scope.kvp.push({
      key: pair[0],
      value: pair[1]
    });
  } else {
    if (index > 0) {
      if ($scope.kvp[$scope.kvp.length - 1]) {
        $scope.kvp[$scope.kvp.length - 1].value += pair[0]; //append last known pair
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/workingClassHacker/shL8od16/7/

Comment: Thank you Espen, Using the ":" to split it in key value pair was a good idea. I will further work on this and get it into the JSON format i require.